# What happened to my basil. I remember only spraying it with dish soap and oil

Tags: diagnosis, basil

I've only ever sprayed dish soap with oil. I usually only water my basil daily but its very rainy in my area. Please help in identifying why my basil has blotches on it's leaves

[image]

Comment: "Iv only ever sprayed dish soap with oil.": There were a reason? It might be just overwatering (so try not to water for a week or so, and maybe put in a place without rain). Do no worry to dry it (Basil is very resilient on dry periods)

Comment: Not much detail on treatment given, make sure: (1) not to use detergent-based soap, this strips away the waxy leaf coating, (2) you wash the excess soap, (3) You do not expose them to direct sun when still wet. Water droplets act like convergent lenses concentrating light into one spot and burning the leaves. (4) Check your mix formula. https://www.gardenguides.com/clean-plant-leaves-dishwashing-fluid-6121.html

Comment: @ChristmasSnow  - that's not true about water droplets acting like lenses (yes, there was on paper supposedly proving this, but it has been debunked - besides, if it were true then we'd see leaf burn everywhere in nature whenever the sun comes out after a rain).